# Rethrowing CryptographicException retains original exception

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have some cryptography code, like this (abbreviated)

```
Public Class Encryption
    Public Sub DoEncryption()
        [...]
        Try
            cryptstream.CopyTo(msVerifyOut)
        Catch ex As System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
            Throw New System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException("Not a valid keyfile or password incorrect", ex)
        End Try
        [...]
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MainClass
    Public Sub UseEncryption
        [...]
        Dim Encrypter As New Encryption
        Try
            Encrypter.DoEncryption()
        Catch ex As System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
            MessageBox.Show("Encryption failed: " & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
        [...]
    End Sub
End Class
```

So the line `cryptstream.CopyTo(msVerifyOut)` may throw a `CryptographicException` which is caught and a new `CryptographicException` is rethrown (with or without the original exception as `InnerException`, doesn't matter here) with a custom message.

I expect the Messagebox to say: `Encryption failed: Not a valid keyfile or password incorrect`. But it doesn't. It says `Encryption failed: Original exception message` instead.

I tried to recreate this like:

```
Private Function Test() As Object
    Try
        Dim tst1 = Test1()
        Return tst1
    Catch ex As CryptographicException
        Throw New CryptographicException("From Test", ex)
    End Try
End Function
Private Function Test1() As Object
    Throw New CryptographicException("From Test1")
End Function
Private Sub PerformTest()
    Try
        Dim tst = Test()
    Catch ex As CryptographicException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But here the Messagebox outputs what I would expect: `From Test`

So there must be some difference in the way the exception is thrown by `cryptstream.CopyTo(msVerifyOut)` than the verification version, but I can't figure out what the difference is.

For reference, the exception thrown is: `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed`. I am not asking WHY the exception is thrown, but why I cannot rethrow it correctly with a different message.

Comment: Is there any other code used to display the Messagebox?  Perhaps that is using GetBaseException().

Comment: @N0Alias No, it's a small program for myself and there is nothing more. When I break on `cryptstream.CopyTo(msVerifyOut)` and step through it just hops into the Catch, throws the new exception, finishes `Using` blocks for the streams and then steps into the outer `Catch` block that contains the Messagebox. I'll see to putting it on Github for the full code later (can't right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. Let's see what actually happens.

I have some code (it's C#, but I believe that you will understand what I mean):

```cs
using (var mem = new MemoryStream(data))
using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mem, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (var bin = new BinaryReader(cryptoStream))
{
    try
    {
        return bin.ReadBytes(data.Length);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid password", ex);
    }
}
```

When I enter the wrong password, I see `CryptographicException` instead of my own `new Exception("Invalid password", ex)`.

Let's look at debug window:

```
"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
"System.Exception" in my.dll
"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" in System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
```

As you can see, my exception is thrown correctly, but after it the new `CryptographicException` is thown again. Therefore, we see an incorrect exception.

The problem is in `CryptoStream.Dispose()` method that calls after exiting from `using` block. It probably calls `FlushFinalBlock()` method, which throw the second `CryptographicException`. More at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7779.

So, move try/catch to outside and you will get what you want:

```cs
try
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(mem, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    using (var bin = new BinaryReader(cryptoStream))
    {
        return bin.ReadBytes(data.Length);
    }
}
catch (CryptographicException ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid password", ex);
}
```

Comment: Neat, that explains it nicely and is really a trap for the uninitiated. And welcome to StackOverflow.